# Finding exponential limit

Tags: limits

> Finding $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^{-n^2}\bigg\{(n+1)\bigg(n+\frac{1}{2017}\bigg)\bigg(n+\frac{1}{2017^2}\bigg)\cdots\cdots \cdots \bigg(n+\frac{1}{2017^{n-1}}\bigg)\bigg\}$$

My Try: Assume $$l=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^{-n^2}\prod^{n}_{r=1}\cdot\bigg(n+\frac{1}{2017^{r-1}}\bigg)$$

$$\ln (l) = -\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^2\ln(n)+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\ln\bigg(n+\frac{1}{2017^{r-1}}\bigg)$$

could some help me how to solve it, thanks

Comment: Seems that the first expression is wrong? Should the $n^{-n^2}$ be to the left of the $\Pi$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each term in parentheses is not larger than $n+1$.  So $l$ is not greater than the limit of $n^{-n^2}(n+1)^{n}$, which is zero.

Comment: There is a typo. There are $n$ terms in the product so you should have $(n+1)^n$ instead of $(n+1)^{n+1}$ but this typo does not make any difference to the answer. Also "smaller" should be replaced with "not greater" because $l$ is equal to $0$. +1 for a simple approach to a complicated looking problem.

Comment: Thanks,but I think that there is no typo.  Notice that besides the 2017 terms there is an additional $n+1$.  Corrected the "smaller".

Comment: you can check again. the number of terms in product is $n$ including the first factor $(n +1)$.

Comment: Oh right I see!  I must be getting old.  At least my argument is still correct even with this typo -:)

Comment: Yes your argument was correct even with the typo (the term $n^{-n^{2}}$ dominates other factor and brings the whole thing down to zero) and that's why you already got an upvote from my end.

Answer (score 0):

My reasoning:

Leave the productory, since you have to be careful about sums and limits inside sums and so on.

The major term of the productory will be $n^n$. The others are neglected by the dominating term $n^{-n^2}$.

Hence you are left with $n^{-n^2 + n}$ .

Which goes to $0$

Comment: Too lazy to write $\lim$. It's understood.

Comment: Actually it is not.

Comment: @Did The productory major term will be $n^n$, the other can be neglected due to the limit. Hence one remains basically with $n^{-n^2 + n}$ which goes as $n^{-n^2}$ which is zero.

Comment: No. Please be aware that using "identities" such as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nx_{k,n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{k,n}$$ is a sure way to reach chaos.

Comment: @Did Oh that! Well my reasoning is independent from that. I could delete that part, actually. My other reasoning was just about using the productory and stop. But if it's wrong then please post an answer so I will learn something :D Productories always confused me.

Comment: Yes, "that". If you have a sound proof, simply post it. (Unrelated: FYI, "Productories" does not seem to be an English word.)

Comment: @Did Haha I know, I am just lazy and many times I invent words :D

Comment: Ah, now we have a precise statement, which is wrong, since the $n$th term is not less than $$n^{-n^2+n}$$

Comment: @Did Ugh. Ok let's do this: wait till I'm at home. Being on a train doesn't help...

Comment: This must be a very slow train.